# How to handle CPU IO spikes while running a cronjob PHP script

Tags: php, cron, cpu-usage

Hey there I am having some CPU spikes due to PHP script I run every 30 mins.
Script sends twits to signed up twitter users everyday and there are a lot of users.
So basically when PHP script sends out twits it causes a CPU spike.

I am asking for a direction on how should I handle this situation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can't you just `nice` the cron job? That way the spikes will still be there, but all other processes that are not nice'd will have precedence once they need cpu power.

Comment: Hope my answer was clear to you, but you accepted it so I guess it was. I also found this interesting article  http://maketecheasier.com/limit-cpu-usage-of-any-process-in-linux/2010/09/22. But to be honest I have not yet tested this, but would like to sometime :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Usleep

Just a tiny little [usleep](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) will return the [CPU to other available process(CPU scheduling)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29).

### Hog

Take this simple script for example:

```
<?php

for ($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++) {
    echo "$i\n";
}
```

This process consumes 20% of my CPU-time on average.

### Schedule

This simple script only consumes 10% CPU-time on averqage.

```
<?php

for ($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++) {
    echo "$i\n";
    usleep(100);
}
```

Of-course this script does take a little longer, but the CPU is better scheduled. The longer you usleep the better the CPU can schedule. `usleep(1000)` for example only used 2% CPU-time.

I tested this on my Ubuntu Box

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.10
Release:    10.10
Codename:   maverick
```

### Message Queue

Also your operating system is very good at scheduling processes(of course that process needs to be friendly to your CPU) so I would advice you to use a message queue to speed up your work(sending tweets). For example [Redis](http://redis.io) can also be used as a message queue or [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/). Run a couple of worker processes which process work(sending out tweets). As a bonus you don't incur the price of spawning processes which is relative expensive. On the web there is more than enough information available using message queue.

Answer (score 1):

Buy more CPU power or [`[u]`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php)[`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) every *`n`* requests.

You can also get the CPU load from [`sys_getloadavg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php) and decide if (and how much) you need to `sleep()`. Bare in mind that sleeping too much may cause each CRON to take longer than 30 minutes.

Comment: Thank you, why the "30 minutes" is a threshold?